# Samsung A20s stuck in safe mode and volume button is completely gone

Tags: samsung, safe-mode

I have Samsung Galaxy A20s. It's stuck in safe mode, and the volume button is completely gone.

I tried all the guides I could find to take off safe mode but my problem is not having volume buttons.

Can I use my PC instead, like USB debugging?

Comment: Sounds to me like at least one volume button is permanently firing even if not pressed. That is a hardware problem that can only be fixed on hardware level - that means you need to repair the volume buttons in a repair shop.

Comment: Wait for the battery to drop.
And do you have USB debugging on?